# Visualizing a multilevel model (HLM) in ggplot2

Tags: r, data-visualization, multilevel-analysis, ggplot2

I have longitudinal data on several countries, looking at GDP and CO2 Emissions. In ggplot2, it is easy to make the software do something HLM-ish by plotting relationships separately for every country:

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=CO2.Emissions, y=GDP, color=as.factor(Country))) + 
   geom_point(shape=20) + 
   geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
   theme(legend.position="none") + 
   scale_y_log10(name="Log10(GDP)") +
   scale_x_log10(name="Log10(CO2 Emissions)")
```

I get the following plot:
[image]

However, this is not a true plot of a multilevel model. I would love to do something LIKE this but visualizing results from a multilevel model. Specifically, the model is:

```
 lmer(GDP ~ 1 + CO2.Emissions + (1 + CO2.Emissions | Country), data=dat )
```

This generates a random slope and intercept for each country. QUESTION: can I plot these and get something similar to (and as aesthetically pleasing as) the ggplot above? I want to visualize the relationships *as depicted in* the model, which ggplot2 is not doing.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you fit an `lmer` model, you can use the `coef()` function to extract the coefficients from the model. Your code would look something like:

```
mod1 <- lmer(GDP ~ 1 + CO2.Emissions + (1 + CO2.Emissions | Country), data=dat)
```

Then you can call `coef()` and extract the coefficients for each group by specifying:

```
coef(mod1)$Country
```

This will give you a vector of intercepts (the '1' you specified in the random term) and slopes (for 'C02.Emissions').

You can then save each of these into their own vector:

```
intercepts <- coef(mod1)$Country[,1] # Specifying the first column only
slopes <- coef(mod1)$Country[,2] # Specifying the second column only
```

Instead of calling `geom_smooth()`, you could then specify specific slopes and intercepts by adding this to your plot:

```
geom_abline(slope=slopes, intercept=intercepts)
```

The positive of this is that it is using the model-implied slopes and intercepts. The downside is that it will extrapolate the lines beyond the values for each cluster (in this case, 'Country').

I would then add another `geom_abline` that is the average slope and intercept, which you can get from:

```
summary(mod1)$coef
```

Another way of doing this—that is not using the model-implied slopes and intercepts—is by specifying `group=cluster`. Using this, it fits a different OLS line for each cluster (which is *not* what the multilevel model fit with `lmer()` is doing, obviously).

I've done this before, and it adapted to your variables would look something like:

```
ggplot(datalong, aes(x=CO2.Emissions, y=GDP, group=Country))+
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, size=.5, color="springgreen") + # slopes for different countries
  stat_smooth(aes(group=1), method="lm", color="blue", size=1.5) + # average slope with SE
```

This might be slightly easier to do, but it will not match up with the model-implied slopes and intercepts you get from the `coef(lmer(...))$cluster` approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to plot `lmer()`objects, I find it easiest to use `predict()`. First you fit your model:

```
random.coef.model <- lmer(GDP ~ 1 + CO2.Emissions + (1 + CO2.Emissions | Country), 
                          data=dat)
```

Then you predict `GDP` values corresponding to your predictor variable (`CO2.Emissions`):

```
dat$random.coefficients.predictions <- predict(random.coef.model)
```

And then you are free to plot them either using `geom_smooth(se=FALSE)` or `geom_line()`. If you want to have a scatterplot at the same time, you need to feed `geom_point()` new `aes()`, as the existing y-values would be the predicted values.  So:

```
random.coef.graph <- ggplot(aes(x = CO2.Emissions, y = random.coefficients.predictions, 
                                color = as.factor(Country)), data = dat) +
geom_line(size=.3) +
geom_point(aes(y = GDP)) +
ggthemes::theme_tufte() #just to make it nice!
```